# woocommerce retriving category name as div class?

Tags: plugins, categories

I am trying to retrieve the category name of a WooCommerce product displayed in a WordPress loop and use it as the class for an `li` (also inside the loop). I've tried this:

```
 <div id="isocontent" class="products">
<ul>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <li class="<?php echo $product->get_categories(); ?> box">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
            <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><span href="<?php the_permalink(); ?> " class="amount price" data-original="<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency(); ?><?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>" data-price="<?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>" title="Original price: <?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>"><?php echo get_woocommerce_currency(); ?><?php echo $product->get_price(); ?></span></a>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>?add-to-cart=<?php echo $post->ID ?>" class="pbutton">Add to Cart</a>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

This is the part where I'm trying to retrieve:

```
<li class="<?php echo $product->get_categories(); ?> box">
```

but it just outputs this:

```
<li class="&lt;a href=" http:="" localhost.no="" fanny="" kategori="" interior-sv="" "="" rel="tag">
```

which not only doesn't retrieve the category but also screws with the markup, breaking the loop.

I've also tried this:

`<li <?php post_class('box'); ?>`

but because WooCommerce uses taxonomies, it retrieves the tags but not the product category.

This question is a follow up on [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96019/woocommerce-product-categories-outside-loop-and-with-pagination).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you haven't set or called the $product object, so it can't access any information in it.

Try inserting `global $product` just before your while loop.

If that doesn't work, try doing a `print_r($product->get_categories()` outside of your html for debugging.

Without the rest of your code I cannot suggest anything else. Also, you should either make sure not more than one category per product is assigned, or take care of that in your code too.